# Catch Fault Exception in Silverlight with Channel Factory

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0, channelfactory

I am trying to call a WCF service from a Silverlight client using channel factory as per this [link](http://blog.kevindockx.com/post/Using-a-Channel-Factory-in-Silverlight-%28instead-of-adding-a-Service-Reference%29-With-cows.aspx). Working with channel factory is something new for me so please bear with me!

Everything mentioned in the article works just fine. But now I am trying to implement Fault exceptions so that I can catch the actual exceptions on the Silverlight side. But for some reason I always end up catching CommunicationException which doesn't serve my purpose.

Here is my service contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(Fault))]
IList<Category> GetCategories();
```

Catch block of the service:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Fault fault = new Fault(ex.Message);
        throw new FaultException<Fault>(fault, "Error occured in the GetCategories service");
    }
```

Service contract for client with async pattern:

```
[OperationContract(AsyncPattern = true)]
[FaultContract(typeof(Fault))]
IAsyncResult BeginGetCategories(AsyncCallback callback, object state);

IList<Category> EndGetCategories(IAsyncResult result);
```

Here is the service call from client:

```
        ICommonServices channel = ChannelProviderFactory.CreateFactory<ICommonServices>(COMMONSERVICE_URL, false);
        var result = channel.BeginGetCategories(
            (asyncResult) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var returnval = channel.EndGetCategories(asyncResult);
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        CategoryCollection = new ObservableCollection<Category>(returnval);
                    });
                }
                catch (FaultException<Fault> serviceFault)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(serviceFault.Message);
                }
                catch (CommunicationException cex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unknown Communications exception occured.");
                }
            }, null
            );
```

I am sharing the DataContract .dll between both the service and client applications and hence they are referring to same data contract classes (Category & Fault)

Please tell me what I am doing wrongly?

**UPDATE**: I do clearly see the fault exception sent from the service in Fiddler. Which makes me believe I am missing something in the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For catching normal exceptions in sivleright you must create "Silverlight-enabled WCF Service" (Add -> New Item -> Silverlight-enabled WCF Service).
If you already created standard WCF service you can add attribute [SilverlightFaultBehavior] to your service manually.
Default implementation of this attribute is:

```
    public class SilverlightFaultBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    private class SilverlightFaultEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new SilverlightFaultMessageInspector());
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
        }

        private class SilverlightFaultMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
        {
            public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
            {
                return null;
            }

            public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
            {
                if ((reply != null) && reply.IsFault)
                {
                    HttpResponseMessageProperty property = new HttpResponseMessageProperty();
                    property.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    reply.Properties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name] = property;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in serviceDescription.Endpoints)
        {
            endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new SilverlightFaultEndpointBehavior());
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to catch normal exceptions. I just want to catch the fault exception that is raised by the service. I thought this was possible without Silverlight Enabled WCF services. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong! This seems to be the only way. Thanks Andris. Below article came in handy for me:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightWCFService.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We use our own custom ServiceException class on the server e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class ServiceException : Exception
{
    public ServiceException()
    {

    }

    public ServiceException(string message, Exception innerException)
        : base(message, innerException)
    {

    }

    public ServiceException(Exception innerException)
        : base("Service Exception Occurred", innerException)
    {

    }

    public ServiceException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {

    }
}
```

And then in our server side service methods we use error handling like this:

```
        try
        {
        ......
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.GetLog(Logger.ServiceLog).Error("MyErrorMessage", ex);
            throw new ServiceException("MyErrorMessage", ex);
        }
```

We then use a generic method for all web service calls:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs the given functon in a try catch block to wrap service exception.
    /// Returns the result of the function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="action">function to run</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Return type of the function.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>The result of the function</returns>
    protected T Run<T>(Func<T> action)
    {
        try
        {
            return action();
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            ServiceLogger.Error(ex);
            throw new FaultException(ex.Message, new FaultCode("ServiceError"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ServiceLogger.Error(ex);
            throw new FaultException(GenericErrorMessage, new FaultCode("ServiceError"));
        }
    }
```